# Control a youtube video in WebView Programmatically

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

I am loading a youtube video in a webview and it works fine, what i wan't is to be able to control the video (i.e start , stop etc.) programmatically. 
I tried a few things and it didn't work

```
 String playVideo= "<html><body><iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/QKm-SOOMC4c?enablejsapi=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer;  autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
 myWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.Webview );
 myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
 myWebView.loadData(playVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
 myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:playVideo()");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at how I'm doing it in this library: [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player).

You can start by looking at the [WebView class](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/pierfrancescosoffritti/androidyoutubeplayer/player/WebViewYouTubePlayer.java).

The idea of calling  `webview.loadUrl("javascript:playVideo()");` is correct. But you need to wait for the IFrame library to be loaded and ready.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, developer can't control that.

Even if developer control that by finding html element by getElementById method and click it, it'll be blocked if Google change the html structure.

I recommend the way is being provided by Google officially.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/